# I use markdown and pandoc and need to renewcommand iffalse/% with a couple tilde

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I use Pandoc and Latex for my adacemic writing with Typora as my markdown editor.
If I need to strikethrough text Typora uses ~~ double tildes.
But Latex didn't recognize it as text which should be hided in PDF outputs. If i use \iffalse text \fi in Typora everything works.

Is there a possibility to use renewcommand or newcommand so that Latex recognizes the tildes?

As a newbie I'm not able to it in the corresponding latex file.

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: hm. calling pandoc panic is a nice error ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal tildes in Markdown for strikethrough, and Pandoc will translate it into the LaTeX `\sout` command. For example:

[image: strikeout test]

```
pandoc -o test.pdf << EOT

~~test~~

EOT
```

Comment: Thanks for the "\sout" hint. That leads me to the solution. If I strike through text in my markdown editor and want the text not compiled within the PDF, my tex file needs this: "\renewcommand{\sout}[1]{\unskip}"